# How to add in-place edit links?

Tags: 7

I need to put in-place links to edit nodes and blocks in Panels. I see that there are some modules in Drupal 6, like [EazyEdit](http://drupal.org/project/eazyedit) and [Block edit](http://drupal.org/project/block_edit), but I didn't find anything for Drupal 7 yet. So appreciate your hints, whether to pick up an existing project on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an alpha version of [Editable Fields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) for Drupal 7. The module:

> allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g. at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected, you can select editable (or click to edit).

It works for nodes, but not for blocks as far as I'm aware.

There's also the [Aloha module](http://drupal.org/project/aloha):

> This module integrates the excellent HTML5 wysiwyg editor Aloha Editor (http://aloha-editor.org/) to Drupal. Both the module and the Aloha Editor library are under active development but still in the early stages.

But judging from the comments on the module page it might not be ready for use just yet. I did find [an article](http://venturacottage.com/tutorials/finally-inline-editor-drupal-7) with someone who claims to have got it working so that might be the place to start.

Comment: Aloha is a nice looking WYSIWYG editor, but its module rendered my site completely unusable, so proceed with caution: there's a reason it's labeled 'beta' ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two more recommendable solution alternatives now:

- [**jEditable**](https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable). A faster but simpler alternative to the already mentioned [Editable Fields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.
- [**QuickEdit**](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit). In-place editor for fields that also allows rich text editing via CKEditor. Base of the in-place editing functionality that will be included in Drupal 8 Core.

Comment: jEditable is only for D6 for D7 there is only dev version. https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable